# Print Preview Fails To Load On Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, printing

I recently encountered an issue with Google Chrome where when attempting to print any webpage from Chrome, the print preview never renders (continues to show `Loading...`) and continuing with the print attempt does not result in the page being printed.

This problem appears to be isolated to a single computer, when signing into my Chrome profile on another computer the print process works fine.

Additionally, when starting Chrome from the command line and setting the `--user-data-dir` flag to something like `/tmp/test_profile`, the print functionality works again. However, the problem persists when using Chrome under a guest account.

With the `--enable-logging` flag set, I observed several errors that resulted when trying to print:

`"Refused to load the script 'chrome-extension://mhjfbmdgcfjbbpaeojofohoefgiehjai/elements/viewer-error-screen/viewer-error-screen.html' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src chrome://resources 'self' 'unsafe-eval'".`

There are an additional 16 error messages that follow, all referencing other components of the `mhjfbmdgcfjbbpaeojofohoefgiehjai` package that failed to load due to the CSP directive.

`mhjfbmdgcfjbbpaeojofohoefgiehjai` referenced in the errors refers to the Chrome PDF Viewer browser plugin, which I believe is installed by default by Chrome and is used in generating the print preview.

I have tried disabling and re-enabling the PDF Viewer plugins several times and have disabled all Chrome extensions to make sure that it was not being affected by outside interference from a misbehaving extension. I have also tried reinstalling Chrome itself.

At this point, I suspect that the problem most likely lies in one of the local files associated with my Chrome profile, given that starting Chrome with a non-existent profile from the command line or using my profile from another computer does not reproduce the issue. However, I'm unsure what exact steps to take next towards identifying the cause. If there are any other details I can provide that would be helpful, please indicate them to me.

Comment: I'm getting the same issue. I just disabled the print preview and forced it to use native print menu by default. Also this issue came about in the recent 56.0.2924.87 update. It was fine before this.

Answer (score 0):

The issue actually appears to lie in the Chrome PDF viewer. I wasn't able to track down the package's location, despite several searches, so I figured I'd try the Chrome Beta Channel to see if it was any better.  And it is!

I resolved the issue by updating to the current Beta channel Chrome (currently 57.0.2987.37 beta (64-bit)) on my Mac.

To do the same, go here: https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/beta.html

Answer (score 0):

I was having an issue with printing from Chrome.  It would endlessly show the print preview menu and not load.  I could print from other programs and I could print if I logged into Chrome using another profile.  I could also print if I was using another computer.
On the offending computer I removed myself as a user (using Manage People).  Then I logged back in - in the top right hand corner was an Orange Exclamation Mark - about extensions.  I enabled the Adobe one - and now I can print! Hurrah